# How to get html content of aspx page after post value by php

Tags: php, asp.net, html

I have a asp.net page:"**abc.aspx**" and a php page:"**def.php**".
I already submit a form from **def.php** with action is **abc.aspx** and it redirect to "**ghi.aspx**" that contain result I need.
How can I get content of **ghi.aspx** when I only have **abc.aspx**'s url.

This's my code in def.php:

`

```
function do_post_request($url, $data, $optional_headers = null)
{
  $params = array('http' => array(
              'method' => 'POST',
              'content' => $data
            ));
  if ($optional_headers !== null) {
    $params['http']['header'] = $optional_headers;
  }
  $ctx = stream_context_create($params);
  $fp = @fopen($url, 'rb', false, $ctx);
  if (!$fp) {
    throw new Exception("Problem with $url, $php_errormsg");
  }
  $response = @stream_get_contents($fp);
  if ($response === false) {
    throw new Exception("Problem reading data from $url, $php_errormsg");
  }
  return $response;
}
if($_POST["submit"])
{
    $data= array(
        '__VIEWSTATE'=>$_POST['vst'],
        'ControlGroupSearchView$AvailabilitySearchInputSearchView$RadioButtonMarketStructure'=>$_POST['ticket_rndtrip'],
        'ControlGroupSearchView$AvailabilitySearchInputSearchView$TextBoxMarketOrigin1'=>$_POST['start_point'],
        'ControlGroupSearchView$AvailabilitySearchInputSearchView$TextBoxMarketDestination1'=>$_POST['end_point'],
        'ControlGroupSearchView$AvailabilitySearchInputSearchView$TextboxDepartureDate1'=>$_POST['depart_day'],
        'ControlGroupSearchView$AvailabilitySearchInputSearchView$TextboxDestinationDate1'=>$_POST['return_day'],
        'ControlGroupSearchView$AvailabilitySearchInputSearchView$DropDownListCurrency'=>$_POST['currency'],
        'ControlGroupSearchView$AvailabilitySearchInputSearchView$DropDownListPassengerType_ADT'=>$_POST['adult_content'],
        'ControlGroupSearchView$AvailabilitySearchInputSearchView$DropDownListPassengerType_CHD'=>$_POST['child_content'],
        'ControlGroupSearchView$AvailabilitySearchInputSearchView$DropDownListPassengerType_INFANT'=>$_POST['infant_content'],
        'ControlGroupSearchView$AvailabilitySearchInputSearchView$RadioButtonSearchBy'=>$_POST['search_by'],
        'ControlGroupSearchView$AvailabilitySearchInputSearchView$numberTrips'=>$_POST['trip_num'],
        'ControlGroupSearchView$AvailabilitySearchInputSearchView$ButtonSubmit'=>$_POST['submit'],
    );
    $url = 'http://abc.aspx';//In my case, I think must be abc.aspx because it redirect to ghi.aspx after post. 
    var_dump(do_post_request($url, $data));
}
?>`

<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<form action="" method="post" id="SkySales">
                <input id="viewState" type="hidden" value="/wEPDwUBMGQYAQUeX19Db250cm9sc1JlcXVpcmVQb3N0QmFja0tleV9fFgEFJ01lbWJlckxvZ2luU2VhcmNoVmlldyRtZW1iZXJfUmVtZW1iZXJtZTxtWS/I2BXFBfalk96y3LBuGXXD" name="vst" xmlns:bookinginfo="urn:bcs:extensions:bookinginfo">
                  <input type="radio" id="ControlGroupSearchView_AvailabilitySearchInputSearchView_RoundTrip" name="ticket_rndtrip" class="radioSingle" autofocus="" value="RoundTrip" checked=""><label for="ControlGroupSearchView_AvailabilitySearchInputSearchView_RoundTrip">Return</label>
                  <input type="radio" id="ControlGroupSearchView_AvailabilitySearchInputSearchView_OneWay" name="ticket_rndtrip" class="radioSingle" value="OneWay"><label for="ControlGroupSearchView_AvailabilitySearchInputSearchView_OneWay">One Way</label>
                  <input type="radio" id="ControlGroupSearchView_AvailabilitySearchInputSearchView_OpenJaw" name="ticket_rndtrip" class="radioMulti" value="OpenJaw"><label for="ControlGroupSearchView_AvailabilitySearchInputSearchView_OpenJaw">MultiCity</label>
                    <input id="ControlGroupSearchView_AvailabilitySearchInputSearchView_TextBoxMarketOrigin1" name="start_point" class="text airport-select location-origin focus-clear" type="text" data-airport-code="" value="Ho Chi Minh City (SGN)" title="Origin" autocomplete="off" data-airportselect-id="1">
                    <input id="ControlGroupSearchView_AvailabilitySearchInputSearchView_TextBoxMarketDestination1" name="end_point" class="text airport-select location-destination focus-clear" type="text" data-airport-code="" title="Destination" value="Hanoi (HAN)" autocomplete="off" data-airportselect-id="2">
                        <label for="ControlGroupSearchView_AvailabilitySearchInputSearchView_TextboxDepartureDate1" class="date" style="display: none; ">Departure</label>
                        <input type="text" id="ControlGroupSearchView_AvailabilitySearchInputSearchView_TextboxDepartureDate1" autocomplete="off" name="depart_day" value="14/08/2012" class="text datepick-depart date-pick hasDatepicker" title="Departure" maxlength="10" data-date="1344877200000">
                        <label for="ControlGroupSearchView_AvailabilitySearchInputSearchView_TextboxDestinationDate1" class="date" style="display: none; ">Return</label>
                        <input type="text" id="ControlGroupSearchView_AvailabilitySearchInputSearchView_TextboxDestinationDate1" autocomplete="off" name="return_day" value="21/08/2012" class="text datepick-return date-pick hasDatepicker" title="Return" maxlength="10" data-date="1345482000000">
                    <label for="ControlGroupSearchView_AvailabilitySearchInputSearchView_DropDownListCurrency" id="ControlGroupSearchView_AvailabilitySearchInputSearchView_DropDownListCurrency_label" style="display:none;">Currency </label>
                    <select id="ControlGroupSearchView_AvailabilitySearchInputSearchView_DropDownListCurrency" name="currency">
                        <option value="VND" selected="selected">Vietnam Dong</option>
                    </select>
                    <label for="ControlGroupSearchView_AvailabilitySearchInputSearchView_DropDownListPassengerType_ADT">Adult</label>
                    <select id="ControlGroupSearchView_AvailabilitySearchInputSearchView_DropDownListPassengerType_ADT" name="adult_content" style="opacity: 1; " class="">
                        <option selected="" value="1">1</option>
                        <option value="2">2</option>
                        <option value="3">3</option>
                        <option value="4">4</option>
                        <option value="5">5</option>
                        <option value="6">6</option>
                        <option value="7">7</option>
                        <option value="8">8</option>
                        <option value="9">9</option>
                        <option value="10">10</option>
                        <option value="11">11</option>
                        <option value="12">12</option>
                        <option value="13">13</option>
                        <option value="14">14</option>
                        <option value="15">15</option>
                        <option value="16">16</option>
                        <option value="17">17</option>
                        <option value="18">18</option>
                        <option value="19">19</option>
                        <option value="20">20</option>
                        <option value="21">21</option>
                        <option value="22">22</option>
                        <option value="23">23</option>
                        <option value="24">24</option>
                        <option value="25">25</option>
                        <option value="26">26</option>
                        <option value="27">27</option>
                        <option value="28">28</option>
                        <option value="29">29</option>
                        <option value="30">30</option>
                        <option value="31">31</option>
                        <option value="32">32</option>
                        <option value="33">33</option>
                        <option value="34">34</option>
                        <option value="35">35</option>
                        <option value="36">36</option>
                        <option value="37">37</option>
                        <option value="38">38</option>
                        <option value="39">39</option>
                        <option value="40">40</option>
                        <option value="41">41</option>
                        <option value="42">42</option>
                        <option value="43">43</option>
                        <option value="44">44</option>
                        <option value="45">45</option>
                        <option value="46">46</option>
                        <option value="47">47</option>
                        <option value="48">48</option>
                        <option value="49">49</option>
                        <option value="50">50</option>
                    </select>
                    <label for="ControlGroupSearchView_AvailabilitySearchInputSearchView_DropDownListPassengerType_CHD">Child<span>2-11</span></label>
                    <select id="ControlGroupSearchView_AvailabilitySearchInputSearchView_DropDownListPassengerType_CHD" name="child_content" style="opacity: 1; " class="">
                        <option selected="" value="0">0</option>
                        <option value="1">1</option>
                        <option value="2">2</option>
                        <option value="3">3</option>
                        <option value="4">4</option>
                        <option value="5">5</option>
                        <option value="6">6</option>
                        <option value="7">7</option>
                        <option value="8">8</option>
                        <option value="9">9</option>
                        <option value="10">10</option>
                    </select>
                    <label for="ControlGroupSearchView_AvailabilitySearchInputSearchView_DropDownListPassengerType_INFANT">Infants<span>&lt;2</span></label>
                    <select id="ControlGroupSearchView_AvailabilitySearchInputSearchView_DropDownListPassengerType_INFANT" name="infant_content" style="opacity: 1; " class="">
                        <option selected="" value="0">0</option>
                        <option value="1">1</option>
                        <option value="2">2</option>
                    </select>
                    <input type="radio" id="ControlGroupSearchView_AvailabilitySearchInputSearchView_SearchStandard" name="search_by" value="SearchStandard" checked="checked">
                    <label for="ControlGroupSearchView_AvailabilitySearchInputSearchView_SearchStandard" class="small">I need to travel on this date</label>
                    <input type="radio" id="ControlGroupSearchView_AvailabilitySearchInputSearchView_SearchLFF" name="search_by" value="SearchLFF">
                    <label for="ControlGroupSearchView_AvailabilitySearchInputSearchView_SearchLFF" class="small">I just want the cheapest flight</label>
                    <input type="hidden" name="trip_num" id="ControlGroupSearchView_AvailabilitySearchInputSearchView_numberTrips" value="2">
                    <input type="submit" id="ControlGroupSearchView_AvailabilitySearchInputSearchView_ButtonSubmit" name="submit" class="png-bg">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think nothing is impossible:D!Thanks for your help!:D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dont submit from def.php to abc.aspx
instead submit from def.php to a proxy script (say prx.php)
for posting from php have a look here: http://wezfurlong.org/blog/2006/nov/http-post-from-php-without-curl/

if you use prx.php, it'll probably get what you want.

Comment: I got this trouble:"Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Problem with http://ghi.aspx, ' in def.php:14 Stack trace: #0 def.php(40): do_post_request('http://ghi.aspx', Array) #1 {main} thrown in def.php on line 14".

Please help me:D!

Comment: Thx very much guys:D! I found [this](http://pastebin.com/sdvthK5j) and it work:D!

Comment: lol i was just looking for your code, anyway you're welcome again