# How to POST parameters to php from terminal

Tags: php, terminal

If I have a file named somephpfile.php, I can execute this from a terminal window using:
"php somephpfile.php"

If I want to pass paramaters to this from the terminal which the php file will receive through  $_POST, how can I do this?

Thanks,

Comment: You could do curl request to pass the data if that's feasible

Comment: sI'm trying to make a server in java which currently correctly receives variables posted to it through HTTP. The java based server then needs to execute the PHP with the variables which have been posted to it. The problem is getting PHP to execute with these variables. Currently I am creating a process which runs "php filename.php" and sends the output back to the client. This works for until I need to add in the parameters which I have in my java server. Perhaps, there is some other way I need to execute php from my java server.

Comment: how do you have parameters in the java server you wish to parse to the php script?

Comment: A socket listens for incoming conections. When a POST request comes in, it is identified as a POST request. Headers are parsed and then the body is parsed, so I will have a set of name value pairs.
For example:
Age: 27
Name: Smith

I then run my php using a process which calls php somefilephp, but I want to pass these to that php file. I can pass them in as args, that seems the best way so far, nut it's not really what I had in mind as I then need to modify the PHP files to take in args rather than POST which is how it should be.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you don't, well not with post:

```
php somephpfile.php var1 var2
```

`$var1` and `$var2` will be in the `$argv` array.

more details: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.argv.php

Comment: This is the closest answer, is it not possible to get these into the $_POST from java in any way?
Thanks,

Comment: I'm not really understanding the java part, so its the best i can think of .

Answer (score 1):

If you want to receive parameters through `$_POST` then you need to host your PHP file in a suitable web container (think Apache + mod-php) and invoke it via an appropriate HTTP request.  It's the web container that sets up `$_POST`.

Anyhow, once you are set up appropriately, the following answer will tell you how to do what you want:

https://superuser.com/questions/149329/what-is-the-curl-command-line-syntax-to-do-a-post-request

Comment: Yes, it is apache libraries I am using on my java based http server. The server takes in the post request, and then needs to execute the PHP to send the result back. How can my java file server take these variables and pass them to the PHP executing process correctly?

Comment: I assume by "apache libraries" and "java based http server" you mean you are running Apache Tomcat?  Quite simply, that is the wrong server to be running if you want to use PHP to generate your content.  You'd be better off either implementing your webservice logic in Java instead of in HTTP, or deploying your PHP-based webapp correctly instead of trying to programmatically bootstrap it from a Java server.

Comment: Or if you really want to do it the hard way, write Java code to dump all parameter values into a JSON object, `Runtime.exec()` a 'bootstrap' PHP file that takes the JSON data and the name of the actual PHP file you want to invoke and manually unpackages the JSON data into `$_POST` before `include`ing the target PHP file, and then  send the result of that back to the caller.  Of course, even if you go with that approach you'll probably find that you're missing other important globals because it's _still the wrong way to accomplish what you're trying to do_.

Answer (score -2):

look here: [How to get html content of aspx page after post value by php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11947419/how-to-get-html-content-of-aspx-page-after-post-value-by-php/11947715#11947715)

you may get the variables as Dagon said, and post them as described in link.

Answer (score -2):

Use telnet do an HTTP POST
See some examples on internet, quick search would give
http://terrencemiao.com/Webmail/msg00197.html