# Execute php file from terminal with POST arguments

Tags: php, post, terminal

I'm trying to execute a piece of php code with the php command in the ubuntu terminal. I'm testing it with a sample code that you can find [here](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp).

I created a file with the code, calling it welcome.php, and tried executing it with:

```
php welcome.php
```

And obviously says there are undefined indexes, because it expects arguments via POST

Obviously I would like to do is to run it with the POST arguments as well. I tried the following:

```
declare -A _POST
_POST[name]="Sample name"
_POST[email]="sample@mail.com"
```

Before executing again, but the result still doesn't show. So is there any way I can declare the POST arguments manually in order to achieve loading the html file properly?

----------------- Context, in case it seems relevant -----------------

I'm programming a modest C server for my studies, and among the functionality required, there is executing php scripts. So my idea is to execute whatever command is required and generate the html output in a file that is later read and transmitted. Parsing the arguments as keys and values is not a problem (although yet to be done).

Comment: Use either $argv or $getopt, check docs. You can also use curl to post from command line.

Comment: [duplicate of an older post with good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13353417/how-to-post-parameters-to-php-from-terminal)

Answer (score 0):

So far I know, you need to create a post request to a `server` to get the $_POST variable's values. In case you want to generate an HTML file, you can pass values through the argument, process it and return (print) an HTML document.